# How to avoid cutting off parts of HTML table when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a large HTML table that I would like to be able to print. Right now, when I print from the latest versions of Chrome or Safari, I get only the first four columns and all of the rows.

I assume there is some CSS that I can add which would allow the the additional columns to be printed on additional pages, but I am not sure what that would be.

I have included a CodePen and the complete HTML below.

[Printing HTML CodePen](https://codepen.io/willieh802/pen/GRKbmBQ)

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
      td { background-color: #e3fcef; }
      th { width: 2in; }
      tr { height: 2in; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;A</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;B</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;C</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;D</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;E</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;F</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;G</th>
            <th style="tableheader">Header&nbsp;H</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td><td>withalongwordthatcannotbeeasilybroken</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Row A</th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
         </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible with pure CSS. You can use javascript to split the table into two tables, see https://forum.jquery.com/topic/divide-a-table

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a more generic solution as I cannot be sure of the size of my table. I am amazed that no one has solved this basic printing problem.